# Impulse response of Time Varying Channel

Tags: digital-communications, time-frequency, time-series

I have just started studying LTV channels in wireless communication.

I know that $y(t) = \int _{-\infty} ^\infty x(t-\tau)h(t,\tau)d\tau$ Is there any way we can calculate the Impulse response $h(t,\tau)$ if we know the input $x(t)$ and output $y(t)$.

Also, can anyone suggest a source to read about the basics of the LTV-Channels? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of wireless communications, the channel impulse response (CIR) is often estimated indirectly via the time-varying transfer function (TVTF) $H(t, f)$, defined by:
$$
H(t, f) = \mathcal F_\tau [ h(t, \tau)]
$$
where $\mathcal F_\tau [ \cdot ]$ denotes the Fourier transform with respect to the $\tau$ (lag) variable.

For example, the air interface for LTE, [E-UTRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-UTRA), uses OFDMA on the downlink. Because OFDM-based schemes do most of the processing in the frequency domain, the TVTF is a more natural representation of the channel.  Values of the TVTF at different time-frequency cells are estimated periodically through the use of [reference symbols](https://frankrayal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/LTE-in-a-Nutshell-Physical-Layer.pdf) that are transmitted in every resource block. Interpolation may be used to estimate the values of $H(t, f)$ at points in between the test points.

As far as references on LTV system theory, I was first introduced to it via the text *Wireless Communications*, by Andrea Goldsmith. Chapter 3 of that book gives a pretty comprehensive overview of the topic. If you are feeling more brave, you can pull Bello's [original paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1088793) on the topic where most of the terminology for basic LTV system theory was laid out (which usage persists to this day). A more recent reference by [Matz](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1532230) expands upon the non-WSSUS case.

If you are interested in estimating the CIR directly in the time-domain, one technique that is used by CDMA-based systems is called a [rake receiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_receiver), which uses a parallel bank of correlators to measure the multipath components (MPCs) at various delay values (i.e. values of $\tau$).  When measuring the CIR in the time-domain, the following lowpass channel model is usually assumed:
$$
h(t, \tau) = \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k(t) e^{j \phi_k(t)} \delta( \tau - \tau_k) 
$$
where $\alpha_k$, $\phi_k$ and $\tau_k$ represent the amplitude shift, phase shift, and lag for a single MPC, indexed by $k$.

Each individual correlator output in a rake receiver is called a "finger". In direct sequence spread spectrum (DSSS), which is the spread spectrum method that 3G CDMA cellular systems use, the transmitted data stream is modulated by a "chip sequence" whose symbol rate is $N$ times higher than the symbol rate of the underlying data stream. This has the effect of "spreading" the signal energy over a bandwidth that is $N$ times larger than the underlying data stream. Each finger of the rake receiver then correlates against the chip sequence to "despread" the signal for a single delay value $\tau_k$. Because the chip sequence has $N$ times better time resolution than the data sequence, it can be used to measure $\alpha_k$ and $\phi_k$ for MPCs whose delays $\tau_k$ are fractions of a symbol period. In other words, each finger of the rake "resolves" a single MPC. Known pilot sequences are transmitted at regular intervals (i.e. different values of $t$), allowing for estimation of $h(t, \tau)$.